# Adding colors to led using FastLED

Tags: arduino, fastled

I am trying to add colors that I set to an led using [FastLED](http://fastled.io/) library on arduino

Currently I am using `fill_solid` like so,

```
leds(8 * CLUSTER, (8 * CLUSTER) + (CLUSTER - 1)).fill_solid(CRGB(255,0 ,0));
FastLED.show();
```

However, I am not able to add colors to it after this has been set. Ideally I would like something like so,

```
leds(8 * CLUSTER, (8 * CLUSTER) + (CLUSTER - 1)).fill_solid(CRGB(255,0 ,0));
FastLED.show();
leds(8 * CLUSTER, (8 * CLUSTER) + (CLUSTER - 1)).fill_solid(CRGB(0,255 ,0));
FastLED.show();
```

And the led would glow with `RGB = (255, 255, 0)`

Is there any way to achieve this without keeping state information and just add to the existing color using FastLED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leds(8 * CLUSTER, (8 * CLUSTER) + (CLUSTER - 1)) += CRGB(0,255,0);  should do what you want (I’m pretty sure I checked that support in for the pixelviews)

Comment: Hmm I tried that .. got --> no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'CPixelView<CRGB>' and 'CRGB')

Comment: I did try  this  --> leds(8 * CLUSTER, (8 * CLUSTER) + (CLUSTER - 1)) = leds(8 * CLUSTER, (8 * CLUSTER) + (CLUSTER - 1)) + CRGB(0,255,0); which give me RGB (0,0,255) Not sure how it gets blue

Comment: Had to do something like --> CRGB(leds[n*CLUSTER].r,leds[n*CLUSTER].g,leds[n*CLUSTER].b ) + CRGB(r,g ,b);

Answer (score 0):

`leds` is just an array of RGB values so you can just iterate through it with a for loop and modify the values. In this case += will work.

For example:

```
for (int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++) leds[i] += CRGB(0,255,0);
```